Light Installation
I'm replacing flush mount lights in my house and when I pulled down the old fixture, there was insulation in the box. I had to remove it to find and connect the ground wire. Should I replace it or leave it out?

A photo would help, as would knowing what's above that ceiling. My guess is that this is just stray blown-in, but that's an unsupported guess.

Older incandescent lamp fixtures often had a layer of fiberglass insulation, to protect the surroundings -- it was not uncommon for the lamps to generate 150 watts of heat or more. Hopefully, you've replaced incandescent lamps with low-power LED's. Since LED lamps need to be kept cool, they might benefit from leaving out the insulation, if that does not invite air leakage from an uninsulated attic.
